# Send ScrollView fling movement to another ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

I have the following code:

```
setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            anotherScrollView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

It clones the touch events in a ScrollView and pass to another, everything are working, but unfortunately, there is a problem. The fling after the finger release is executed in the primary ScrollView but the `dispatchTouchEvent` does not send it to the another ScrollView. If I scroll the primary very fast, release the finger and use `dispatchTouchEvent`, the another ScrollView will do nothing because the fling isn't send.

Comment: what do you mean by "other ScrollView"," another "... those point is not clear ....

Comment: I have two ScrollViews, I need clone the movement of one and send to another. It works when the user scroll the first one using the finger, but when the finger is released and the ScrollView begin fling, this movement isn't send through `dispatchTouchEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        anotherScrollView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        return true; // try to add this
    }
    return false;
}
```